# Collision Event in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am wondering how to make my collision work correctly in Corona. Here is what I have so far:

```
local function onLocalCollision( event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

    print( "began: " .. event.object1.myName .. " and " .. event.object2.myName )
    test =  display.newRect(screenW - 50, halfH, 100, screenH)


elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

    print( "ended: " .. event.object1.myName .. " and " .. event.object2.myName )

end

lilPig.collision = onLocalCollision
lilPig:addEventListener( "collision", lilPig )

endOfScreen.collision = onLocalCollision
endOfScreen:addEventListener( "collision", endOfScreen )
```

If you could help me that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think, firstly you should add some property with your COLLISION objects, like:

```
lilPig.myName = "lilPig"

endOfScreen.myName = "endOfScreen"
```

so, we can directly check them in Collision listener and also if we have more Collision's after that, we can easily check by another condition.

we can also implement it by RunTime listener.

```
--------

RuntimeListener("collision", onCollision )

--------



function onCollision( event)
        if (event.phase == "began") then
        print("COLLISION: ".. event.object1.myName .. " & ".. event.object2.myName)

            if (event.object1.myName == "lilPig" and event.object2.myName == "endOfScreen") or
                   (event.object1.myName == "endOfScreen" and event.object2.myName == "lilPig") then

                            print("Your code of block for collision event")

end
```

Comment: Ok I did what you said, but the Runtime Listener was a undeclared global value. This is probably a noob question, sorry.

Comment: I actually figured out that part but now I have a different issue. It says the myName is a nil value and there is a problem with that. Any ideas?